# MSAccess: "Append" from CSV into Access Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I can create a new TABLE without issue using the following approach:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
strFile = "Item_9766.csv"
strPath = "c:\users\mark\desktop"

strSQL = "SELECT * INTO newTable FROM [Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited;Database=" & strPath & "]." & strFile & ";"
db.Execute (strSQL)
```

However, when trying a similar approach to APPEND to an existing Table, Access complains "*The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'F1'*"

```
strSQL = "Insert INTO myTable Select * FROM [Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited;Database=" & strPath & "]." & strFile & ";"
```

Any suggestions to correct?  CSV file is comma delimited, with " text qualifier, no headers.  TransferText approach was taking too long with large 550K x 50 column CSV file.

Comment: Does the table `newTable` created using the `SELECT INTO` statement have the same number of fields as the `myTable` table?

Comment: Huh, great point.  The column counts do not match.

Comment: newTable = 42 columns, myTable = 45 columns.  There is data in the 3 missing columns.

Comment: OK, confirmed our processes do add the 3 extra columns downstream from the data import.

Comment: So the CSV generates 42 columns? Open myTable in design view. Are the additional 3 columns located at end of the fields list? If not, move them there and then try the INSERT SELECT.

Comment: Yes, The extra columns are already at the end of the field list.

Comment: INSERT SELECT fails w/same message even into a 42 column destination.

Comment: Thinking I will just PUNT, import as a New Table and accommodate as needed.  was taking ~4mins using TransferText on this last large set.  Above approach takes 17sec.  Plenty of time to spare, ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try it this way without the '*'.

```
Private Sub InsertRecordsFromCSV()

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblTest " & "SELECT ID, ZIP_CODE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, CITY, STATE, COUNTY, TYPE " & "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & dataPath & ";].[zips.csv];"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Catch ex1 As Exception
        MsgBox(ex1.ToString)
    Finally
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```